# Pandas collapse rows by value into tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to collapse a dataframe with values with the same title, into an entry with that title but a tuple for the date. The dataframe is already sorted by identifier, and then by date.

This is what my data looks like:

```
identifier    title     date
123           "Pres"    2019-01-01
123           "Pres"    2020-01-01
123           "CEO"     2020-06-01
```

And I'd like to collapse it into something like this (based on the title matching the previous one):

```
identifier    title     date
123           "Pres"    (2019-01-01, 2020-01-01)
123           "CEO"     (2020-01-01, 2020-06-01)
```

Anyone have an idea of what function is best to do this? I've tried groupby and agg but couldn't get those to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df = df.groupby(['identifier', 'title'], as_index=False).agg(tuple)
print(df)

   identifier title                      date
0         123   CEO             (2020-06-01,)
1         123  Pres  (2019-01-01, 2020-01-01)
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks @NYC Coder, i learnt something new today.